# Rotation Continuity help

Tags: c#, xna, rotation, monogame

First the issue im having: Basically its the fact that the angles of a circle aren't continuous, they rise from 0 to 2pi then immediately fall back to 0.

I want to make a game where the player controls a tank and ive got a tank drive working but i want to implement a "Directional Drive" where the player can push a joy stick(XBOX360) in a certain direction and the tank will move forward and turn towards this direction. 
heres the code i have to do that:

```
if (Math.Abs(controllerCOORD.Y) > Deadzone || Math.Abs(controllerCOORD.X) > Deadzone)
        {
            decimal intended_angle = (decimal)Math.Atan2(controllerCOORD.X, controllerCOORD.Y);

            double correction = (double)Decimal.Round((intended_angle - (decimal)this.BaseAngle_Rad), 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

            this.BaseAngle_Rad += (correction / demultiplier_rot);

            this._x_pos += ((float)Math.Sin(this.BaseAngle_Rad) * multiplier_pos); //x component vector of movement
            this._y_pos -= ((float)Math.Cos(this.BaseAngle_Rad) * multiplier_pos); //y component vector of movement
        }
```

Unfortunately with this code, when the player pushed the joystick downwards(0,1), the angle it calculates approches pi from the right side and negative pi from the left side causing it to make a full turn in the wrong direction instead of like a few degrees in the correct direction.

How do i make the rotation continuous all the way around?
Ive already found these two questions on here but neither is helping me:

[360+ degree rotation skips back to 0 degrees when using Math.Atan2(y, x)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46552/360-degree-rotation-skips-back-to-0-degrees-when-using-math-atan2y-x)

[Turning a sprite such that it rotates in the direction that's most efficient](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14900/turning-a-sprite-such-that-it-rotates-in-the-direction-thats-most-efficient)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I misread one of the links I posted and it turned out to be more helpful than I thought.

The working code sample:

```
if (Math.Abs(controllerCOORD.Y) > Deadzone || Math.Abs(controllerCOORD.X) > Deadzone)
{
    double intended_angle = Math.Atan2(controllerCOORD.X, controllerCOORD.Y);
    double current_angle = this.BaseAngle_Rad % MathHelper.TwoPi;
    double difference = ((intended_angle - current_angle + MathHelper.Pi) % MathHelper.TwoPi) - MathHelper.Pi;
    if (intended_angle > current_angle + MathHelper.Pi)
    {
        intended_angle -= 2 * MathHelper.Pi;
    }
    else if (intended_angle < current_angle - MathHelper.Pi)
    {
        intended_angle += 2 * MathHelper.Pi;
    }
    this.BaseAngle_Rad = MathHelper.Lerp((float)current_angle, 
                                         (float)intended_angle, 
                                         2.5f * (float)gametime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds);
    this._x_pos += ((float)Math.Sin(this.BaseAngle_Rad) * multiplier_pos); //x component vector of movement
    this._y_pos -= ((float)Math.Cos(this.BaseAngle_Rad) * multiplier_pos); //y component vector of movement
}
```